# 'Because Kei Shirogane, is a mother flippin' tsundere'?

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

For the english dub of Kaguya-sama, which episode is the "Because Kei Shirogane, is a mother flippin' tsundere" please? It doesn't seem to be in S02E10 or S02E02, but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVfylQJz1Qg&t=250s) suggests it's in S02E10 specifically in 'Kei Shirogane Can't Speak'.

Comment: Found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DSRoAVICF4c) that also states the scene is from season 2 episode 10.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ah I got it. It's not from the specific story 'Kei Shirogane Can't Speak' of S02E10. It's in the prologue BEFORE the opening of S02E10. I couldn't find it because I was looking in the sub-episode proper 'Kei Shirogane Can't Speak.'