# Kei Shirogane doesn't care in S02E10 vs steals Miyuki's phone in S03E04

Tags: kaguya-sama-love-is-war

Why in [S02E10](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66603/because-kei-shirogane-is-a-mother-flippin-tsundere) does Kei not want to show any interest in Miyuki's love life despite being extremely interested and yet in [S03E04](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Episode_28) (specifically [Ch106](https://kaguyasama-wa-kokurasetai.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_106)) when Chika brings up Miyuki's love life, Kei automatically butts in and a fortiori shows interest?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I was told. I'm posting this here as part of Cunningham's Law:

> Since there's an external factor, namely of that Chika brought up Miyuki's love life, there's no reason for Kei to be embarrassed anymore.

**Edit**: Wait there's another thing. Kei actually says that Miyuki's love life was distracting or something and so wanted to tell Chika about it in hopes of reducing the distraction. Of course this may have been a lie.